# how to change TTNavigator (for a web url) bottom bar color?

Tags: three20, uinavigationbar, ttnavigator

Here is a code i made to open a website via TTNavigator-

```
- (IBAction)btnTemp_Click{

    TTNavigator* navigator = [TTNavigator navigator];
    navigator.supportsShakeToReload = YES;
    navigator.persistenceMode = TTNavigatorPersistenceModeAll;

    [navigator openURLAction:[[TTURLAction actionWithURLPath:@"http://www.google.com"] applyAnimated:YES]];
}
```

and here i was able to manage its navigation bar items, color etc-

```
- (void)addSubcontroller:(UIViewController *)controller animated:(BOOL)animated transition:(UIViewAnimationTransition)transition 
{
    [self.navigationController addSubcontroller:controller animated:animated transition:transition];

    UIButton *btnBack =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btnBack setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navback.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnBack addTarget:self action:@selector(popThisView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [btnBack setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 32, 32)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btnBack];

    UIBarButtonItem *backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btnBack];
    [controller.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:backBarButtonItem animated:YES];

    [btnBack release];
    TT_RELEASE_SAFELY(backBarButtonItem);
}
```

but i am not able to change color of bottom bar that has back, fwd, stop and refresh bottons.

Anybody please help. It must be done because i saw this in different colors on many applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changing the colors and style of the toolbars should be done using a TTStyleSheet class.

First, you should extend the TTDefaultStyleSheet to your own class and include these functions to change the colors for both the `UINavigationBar` and the lower `UIToolbar`:

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark TTDefaultStyleSheet


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
- (UIColor*)navigationBarTintColor {
  return RGBCOLOR(0, 60, 30);
}


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
- (UIColor*)toolbarTintColor {
  return RGBCOLOR(0, 60, 30);
}
```

Then you should load your style sheet class into your app delegate:

```
[[[TTStyleSheet setGlobalStyleSheet:[[[StyleSheet alloc] init] autorelease]];
```

Comment: could you please tell me how i can make the navigationbar text to blank or with clear color? Please tell me if possible. i could not found any related method on its class reference at http://api.three20.info/interface_t_t_default_style_sheet.php. I have a requirement and i'm already overriding navigation bar with a image. and in this case Text (title text of a webpage) appears over the navigationbar image

Answer (score 0):

Thanx aporat,
Here is the stuff i did-

1. Created a new class (simply as new viewcontroller is created) with
   name `Stylesheet.h` and `Stylesheet.m`
2. imported `#import <Three20Style/Three20Style.h>` in `.h` file
3. replaced `UIViewController` with `TTDefaultStyleSheet`
4. in `.m` file i put the methods `navigationBarTintColor` and `toolbarTintColor`
5. in project delegate file first i imported `Stylesheet.h` then on the 1st line of `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` i placed `[TTStyleSheet setGlobalStyleSheet:[[[Stylesheet alloc] init] autorelease]];`

THATS IT :)